# "var g = myComponent?.gameObject" gives an error but " var g = myComponent == null ? null : myComponent.gameObject" does not

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As the title basically says, I have a local variable which we can call `myComponent` which is a type of Monobehaviour. Well, it's really `myOtherComponent.myComponent`, but `myOtherComponent` is *never* changed after `Start()` so I don't see how it could change anything especially since the following is the only thing I change about my code:

```
var g = myComponent?.gameObject;
if(g != null) {  /* sometimes does: */  Destroy(myComponent); }
else {  /* sometimes does: */  myComponent = Instantiate(); }
```

"MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'BlockPreview' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object. [Then there is a link directly to that `var g` line.]"

But when I change that code to this:

```
var g = myComponent == null ? null : myComponent.gameObject;
if(g != null) {  /* sometimes does: */  Destroy(myComponent); }
else {  /* sometimes does: */  myComponent = Instantiate(); }
```

No errors. It works perfectly fine.

But from what I know (and just googled), then `myComponent?.gameObject` is literally just shorthand for `myComponent == null ? null : myComponent.gameObject`.

I know I could write this a lot better, like replace the variable in `myOtherComponent` from a `MyComponent` type to a `GameObject` type, for example, but I would like to know why this is happening to avoid it in the future. Although, it almost seems like a bug in Unity, but I have no idea.

Comment: Unity does not behave the same as idiomatic C#.  I think this is a quirk caused by how Unity represents and evaluates null objects.

Comment: This is a good discovery, but where question? :)

Comment: I think this is a possible duplicate of [How am I misusing the null-coalescing operator? Is this evaluating “null” correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56875706/how-am-i-misusing-the-null-coalescing-operator-is-this-evaluating-null-correc).  Same issue, different operator, same reason.  Unity overloads `==` but can't overload `??` or `?.`, so their behavior is inconsistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oficial Unity support responce

> UnityEngine.Object and those who inherit it, do not support null conditional operator.
>   The Docs are updated to reflect this

https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/c-number-6-null-conditional-access-operator-dot-throws-missingcomponentexception-instead-of-recognizing-as-null

Comment: Using Unity 2019.2.5 and VS 2019 I actually get a warning for it: `'?' on a type deriving from 'Unity.Object' bypasses the lifetime check on the underlying Unity engine object`. In general you should never use `== null` for Unity `Object` **at all** rather use `if(g)` since even if the object appears to be `null` Unity actually stores some shadow information in the according reference for e.g. throwing the according exception with a hint to **why** this object is `null`

Comment: Looks like it is ReSharper feature. Same notification for Unity 2018.4.5 + VS CE 2017 with ReSharper

Comment: VisualStudio often takes a lot of features from ReSharper and implements them directly itself in new Updates ;) possible that they added it in 2019