# Destroy cloned prefabs after bounds distance reached unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation, destroy, bounds, collider

I'm trying to destroy cloned prefabs when they reach the bound on the x axis of a cube. But when the first clone is destroyed, an error occur, and the next appearing clone won't destroy.

Error:

> MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
> Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.
> deploy.Update () (at Assets/deploy.cs:52)

This is the script attached to the cube:

```cs
public class deploy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject starsPrefab;    
    private GameObject star;
    public float respawnTime=40.0f;

    Vector3 bsize,bmax,bmin,plane;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(starsWave());
        Collider bCollider = this.GetComponent<Collider>();

        bsize=bCollider.bounds.size;
        bmax=bCollider.bounds.max;
        bmin=bCollider.bounds.min;

        //Vector3 plane=new Vector3(bmax.x-bmin.x,bmax.y-bmin.y,bmax.z-bmin.z);
    }

    private void spawnStar()
    {
        star =Instantiate(starsPrefab) as GameObject;
        star.transform.position= new Vector2(bsize.x,Random.Range(-bsize.y,bsize.y));
    }
   
    IEnumerator starsWave()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            spawnStar();

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(respawnTime);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(star.transform.position.x<bmin.x)
        {
            Destroy(star);
        }
    }
```

If I increase `respawnTime`, the same error occurs; the first clone appears, it reaches the bound, it's destroyed, there's the same error, a second clone appear afterwards, it reaches the bound, it's destroyed, there's the same error,&hellip

It seems that Destroy() is applied to the last cloned star, how can I apply this to any cloned star?

Comment: You spawn potentially many stars but only remember the last spwned.

Comment: Is there any way to remember all stars?

Comment: @lemmecatch use a `List<GameObject>` instead a single reference?

Comment: @derHugo thank you for your suggestion I'm going to try, I 'm new to coding and unity so I don't know exactly where to look for

Comment: Words like "solved" and "updated" are not to be put in Stack Overflow question titles. The revision history indicates when a post has been "updated", and if the question has been answered, the answer posted below the question that best addresses the question should be accepted (click check-mark button). If you have solved the question yourself, post your own answer and accept it. Don't post solutions in the question; it makes them hard for others to find and read.

Answer (score -1):

You are destroying `star` but you are still checking his position in the Update()

You can easily fix this by changing your if with

```
 `if(star!= null)`
{
if(star.transform.position.x<bmin.x)
{
Destroy(star)
}}
```

So if star is destroyed, it is no longer checked

Comment: Hello thank you for your quick reply, I just changed that but the problem is the same

Comment: uh it's because you are first checking the star, look at my answer edited :D @lemmecatch

Comment: There's no error. I decreased the speed of star moving in negative direction on x axis ( a script is attached to the starPrefabs with a float speed), but none of the star will destroy they continue to move outside the bmin.x

Comment: with the new code it will work, check my edit @lemmecatch

Comment: Yes I tried with the new code, but it works only one  at a time so if there is more than 1 star visible, destroy doesn't work (I played with the speed here) If there s only one passing then the code works (it goes quickly and it destroys before a second star appear)

Comment: You should **never** use a `!=null` check for anything deriving from `UnityEngine.Object` see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60189474/7111561) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56875706/how-am-i-misusing-the-null-coalescing-operator-is-this-evaluating-null-correc)